# Jasperreports 5.6 as a module on JBoss EAP 6.1 error

Tags: java, jboss, jasper-reports, jboss6.x

My module.xml is below. I am deploying app as JAR. I tried to google this error, but of no avail. All recommendations I see is to include JDT compiler to the app, I added it to the jasperreports module in JBoss, and to the POM, but the result is the same.
How to resolve it?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="net.sf.jasperreports">
        <resources>
            <resource-root path="jasperreports-5.6.0.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="itext-2.1.7.js2.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="jcommon-1.0.15.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="jfreechart-1.0.12.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="xml-apis-1.3.02.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="jdtcore-3.1.0.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="castor-1.2.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="jackson-core-2.1.4.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="jackson-databind-2.1.4.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="jackson-annotations-2.1.4.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lucene-core-4.5.1.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lucene-analyzers-common-4.5.1.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="lucene-queryparser-4.5.1.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="olap4j-0.9.7.309-JS-3.jar"/>
            <resource-root path="jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar"/>
        </resources>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.api"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.beanutils"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.collections"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.digester"/>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
        </dependencies>
</module>
```

I know it's reachable because I stopped receiving errors about dependencies after placing them in the module folder.

I have following error while trying to execute the report, the top of the trace is here, and as I understand this error is common, but I still cannot resolve it:

```
    21:19:00,471 ERROR [ru.reporter.ReportServiceBean] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8180-1) [2][admin] Got exception while in buildMonitoringReport: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
C:\JBOSS-SY\bin\report2_1403803139200_531972.java:4: error: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*;
^
C:\JBOSS-SY\bin\report2_1403803139200_531972.java:5: error: package net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill does not exist
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<resource-root path="jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar"/>` from your module and dependency as `<module name="org.jboss.as.web"/>`

Check org.jboss.as.web, it should already have jdt-compiler which conflicts with the one in your module.